# Question about updating web.config file after upgrading from asp.net MVC 5.2.4 to 5.2.7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which I upgraded to use asp.net mvc 5.2.7 from 5.2.4

After the upgrade my package.config file was updated to reflect the change:

From : `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.4" targetFramework="net452" />`

To   : `<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net452" />`

However in my web.config file inside of the views folder it still says:

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="WebApplication2" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

AND.....

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

Do i need to change this here to 5.2.7.0 ?

The application seems to be working fine with out the change... I'm not sure why this works though.. can somone please explain why this is the case?

Update: now it seems like it doesn't really matter what value i put inside of the web.config file.. the application works regardless.... why is this the case?...

Comment: hmm... this question isn't really on-topic.  It's equivalent to "Why is this working" and it's probably only going to invite guesses, discussions and subjectivity with so little information.  As such, I'll guess that there is a rebind to these known system assemblies defined somewhere.  Have you tried changing the version? what is in your obj folder?

Comment: yup. but i'm trying to figure out where its coming from.. i tried changing the version and it still works.. cleared out everything in obj and bin folders.. still works..

Comment: What does your `packages.config` state for the version? I'm interested to know this as well, as I've run into issues here and there when upgraded packages from NuGet (not necessarily Mvc, but other libraries)

Comment: @rob scott it says 5.2.7

Comment: @psj01 If your packages.config says 5.2.7, and your `dll` in your references has the same version, then your `web.config` in your `Views` folder(s) and your main should be the same. Did you actually run the `Update-Package ......`?  I would do a reinstall of all packages (backup your project if possible). I would bank that there are some other dependencies to Mvc that didn't update

Comment: After updating to 5.2.7, the package.config got updated... but web.config in views didnt get updated to say version 5.2.7... but the application still works... i thought it was going to throw error saying there is a mismatch

Comment: The web.config file in the root folder got updated as well...(pointing to 5.2.7.0)